# Display quantity on product loop adding in the cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization, hook-woocommerce

In the woo commerce, How can I display quantity on the product listing page? Suppose if I have added product `x` product with **3** quantity and `y` with **5** quantity in the cart. Then in the product listing page should display **3** quantity added for `x` and **5** for `y`.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it . You need to access the cart items and check quantity. I have tested with latest WP 5.8.1 and latest Woo 5.6.0 with Storefront theme.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        // Access the cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
            $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
        // If we have match update quantity
        if($product_id == $product->get_ID()) {
            $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array('input_value' => $quantity), $product, false );
        } else {
            $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        }
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```